# Spring Webflux Security Allow All But One Url

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I want to allow all urls defined in a specific controller except one.

Let's say my controller exposes 3 urls with base url `/users`

1. "/" list all users
2. "/{id}" list user by id
3. "/admin" get admin level details of user.

I want to allow access to 1 and 2 urls to any user except the last one.

I have been doing something like this

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/users/**")
        .permitAll()
        .pathMatchers("/users/admin")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
    return http.build();
}
```

But it is not working. I have tried the reverse also i.e.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/users/admin")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyExchange()
        .authenticated()
        .pathMatchers("/users/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .formLogin();
    return http.build();
}
```

This is also not working stating that since `anyExchange()` is already registered next `pathMatcher` can't be reached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution.
`anyExchange()` and `authenticated()` was causing the issue. `anyExchange()` was not allowing to add any path matcher further and `authenticated()` was making the whole app secured one causing each url to prompt for authentication.

Removing these two worked.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/users/admin/**")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().httpBasic();
    return http.build();
}
```